# Localhost not running anytime i run Microstrategy Web

Tags: iis, microstrategy

Initially when i installed Microstrategy Analytics Enterprise, i could run Microstrategy Web.

But after unchecking and then checking back IIS services in "Turn Windows Features Off or On" and then restarting my system, i cannot access Microstrategy Web on my browser.It keeps saying Unable to connect, Can't establish a connection to localhost

I haave tried restarting Microstrategy services in "Services", restarting my browsers, but all to no avail.

Please how do i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install MicroStrategy again ?

Comment: I did. But I got the same old result.

Comment: Is only the MSTR app that doesnt work ? Did you try other web app on the same IIS ?

Comment: I didn't. MSTR is the only web app running on IIS. Other web apps run on Wampserver or Glassfish

Comment: So I would went for adding some very simple app to check if it is hosted correctly as the issue might be more of IIS than MSTR specific and it is simple way to isolate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check that you are connected with the correct I-server machine in web administrator.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34891077)